# Google appengine - http://[appname].appspot.com/

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a home servlet created in my google app engine application which I am using to perform some admin functions. This can be accessed using the URL - http://[appname].appspot.com/
Is there any way that I can restrict access to this servlet to myself only? Currently this is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add security though your [web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication) with validation from your google account. There are a number of options, so its hard to advise based on your current question